# :hover class not registering in browser

Tags: html, css, hover

HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>vinyl</title>    
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href="css/indexstyles.css"> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class = "sleeve">
            <div class = "album"><div class = "innerhole"></div></div>    
        </div>
    </body>    
</html>
```

CSS code

```
.album {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #2C3E50;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.album :hover{background: white;}

.innerhole{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:-50px;
    margin-left:-50px;
    background: #E00000;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


body { background: #CCB07A url('http://i.imgur.com/uNVzcoX.png') repeat; }
```

In this program I am trying to implement the :hover pseudo class on the album class. I have tried to do this but have found that it has not been registering at all on the browser. I have also checked that it is not a compiler issue. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any `:hover` in your example. Also, what's with the `$`s?

Comment: I tried using :hover before on the album class. I'll update the code. As for the $'s, they are to edit the background. I will be editing them later. Take them out if you like.

Comment: Please show the rendered CSS, or identify that you're code is actually SASS/LESS, not CSS.

Comment: Your code is working perfectly..Check this http://jsfiddle.net/dL45hb7e/

Comment: I was trying to get it to register when the mouse was above the outer circle, not the inner one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and there was a space after album in `album:hover`..
I tried that in jsfiddle

`:hover` is working very well

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dL45hb7e/1/) for more details..

Comment: I was trying to get it to register when the mouse was above the outer circle, not the inner one

Comment: there was a space after `album` in `album:hover`. That was why it dint work.Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dL45hb7e/1/)